# Operator precedence: multiple expressions with && and ||

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, operator-precedence

I encountered a code line that looks like this:

```
if ($users == 'all' || $_POST['user'] == 1 && $users == 'admins' || $_POST[ 'user' ] == 0 && $users == 'mods') ...
```

I don't understand how are all these conditions met because there are not parentheses between them :(

Is `||` more important than `&&` ? Which parts get evaluated first?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Of course the order of operators is well defined, as in any decent programming language. See [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: I use **Nandos** as a mnemonic: **N**ot, **and**, **o**r, **s**hortest form first. Giving ~,!,&,|,&&,||,AND,OR

Comment: NANDOS is a cool idea, but I would add the "e" for "equals" (which also includes `>` and `<`), thus NEANDOS.  I'm slightly confused what you mean by "shortest form" though, so I might personally change it to NEANDOR until I can clarify that bit.

Comment: Duh. Never mind, I figured it out. NEANDOS it is :-)

Answer (score 12):

`&&` depends of the evaluation of the right expression when left one is true, `||` doesn't. You could rewrite it to:

```
if(
    $users == 'all' ||
    ($_POST['user'] == 1 && $users == 'admins') ||
    ($_POST['user'] == 0 && $users == 'mods')
)
```

And it'll be the same.

Answer (score 1):

With no parenthesis, PHP will evaluate each expression from left to right, using PHP's [operator precedence](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) along the way.  However, as in any logical check, throwing `AND` into the mix can make things confusing and a lot harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

It starts out going from left to right unless precedence takes over.

```
function rtrue($x) {
    static $rt = 0;
    echo $x . ' called true ' . ++$rt . '<br>';
    return true;
}

function rfalse($x) {
    static $rf = 0;
    echo $x . ' called false ' . ++$rf . '<br>';
    return false;
}

// all but last get called, eq: false || (true && false) || (false && true)
$result1 = rfalse('a') || rtrue('b') && rfalse('c') || rfalse('d') && rtrue('e');
echo '=== result '. ( $result1 ? 'true' : 'false' ) . '<br>';

// first true does not get called, eq: (false && true) || true
$result2 = rfalse('x') && rtrue('y') || rtrue('z');
echo '=== result '. ( $result2 ? 'true' : 'false' ) . '<br>';
```

Prints the following:

```
a called false 1
b called true 1
c called false 2
d called false 3
=== result false
x called false 4
z called true 2
=== result true
```

Comment: No, this explains his question. The language (in this case) is irrelevant.