# Why doesn't my IF ($a || $b && $c) statement work as expected (PHP operator precedence)

Tags: php, if-statement, operator-precedence

Over the years I have noticed that there are a lot of PHP programmers who don't understand the importance of making sure you always include parentheses, even when it is "not needed." (hint: it is **always** needed)

#### Example Scenario:

You are tasked with updating the login page to allow the usage of either their existing password or a login token with a username.

**The existing code looks something like this:**

```
if ($password_is_valid && $username_is_valid) {
    // Success
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

**You update the code to look like this:**

```
if ($password_is_valid || $token_is_valid && $username_is_valid) {
    // Success
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

After a few tests to make sure that users can still login, you confirm all is well and call it a day. Fast-forward a few weeks or months and your manager is yelling at you to find out how one of the sales staff was able to login as an admin and give himself a raise without knowing that admin's password.

After reading through all the login code 3 times over you are completely in the dark of how this could happen. Finally you resort to some manual testing, and eventually you find out that anyone's correct password will work with anyone else's username, as long as that username actually exists in the database.

How is this possible?

---

**Please Note:** This post is purely to help newer/less-seasoned developers with a common problem based on a misunderstanding of how `&&` and `||` work together. I did try to find a similar post on S.O. however I wasn't able to find one, or at least not for PHP.

Comment: and what's about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138269/multiple-boolean-conditions-operator-precedence ?

Comment: @kuh-chan That didn't show up in my particular search... which is odd. Although, if it helps my post does give better insight as to what's going on.

Comment: @miken32 While I agree they both have the same core question, the Q&A here is clearer and does give better understanding without requiring SO users to leave the site. Additionally, the answer here if fundamentally different in that it suggests a simple solution over asking the user to read several pages a documentation.

Comment: Then I suggest you post an answer to the existing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you misunderstand [how operator precedence works in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). However, that explanation is far too detailed and outside the scope of this question.

The simplest and best answer is to make sure you always use parentheses whenever mixing operators **AND/OR** whenever it may not be clear what should be evaluated first.

In the context of our example scenario, the updated code **should** have looked like this:

```
if (($password_is_valid || $token_is_valid) && $username_is_valid) {
    // Success
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

However, because the updated code *did not have parentheses to specify what order to run the operations*, **PHP interpreted it like this**:

```
if ($password_is_valid || ($token_is_valid && $username_is_valid)) {
    // Success
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

If you are still confused, this is a code sample that you can play with to get a better understanding of this issue: https://3v4l.org/SmIip

**Furthermore**, even when parentheses *"really aren't needed to function as desired"* they will make your code more readable and easier to understand. Which will be important to the next dev who will read your code. (which may in fact be you in 6+ months when you have forgotten what you were thinking when you wrote it.) So just always add them, even when your sure they "aren't needed."