# Is this a bug in PHP null coalesce operator or expected behaviour?

Tags: php, null-coalescing-operator

I've stumbled about an if statement, using PHPs null coalesce operator, not behaving as "expected". The code in question looks something like this:

```
if ($foo['bar'] ?? false || $foo['baz'] ?? false) { /* ... */ }
```

changing it to

```
if (($foo['bar'] ?? false) || ($foo['baz'] ?? false)) { /* ... */ }
```

solves it.

I ran a quick test in my terminal:

```
root@docker:/application# php -v
PHP 7.2.11-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 15 2018 11:40:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.11-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
root@docker:/application# php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $test = ['foo' => 'bar'];
php > var_dump($test['baz'] ?? null); // as expected
php shell code:1:
NULL
php > var_dump(($test['baz'] ?? null)); // as expected
php shell code:1:
NULL
php > var_dump($test['baz'] ?? null || $test['foobar'] ?? null); // as expected, but there's a Notice
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: foobar in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
php shell code:1:
bool(false)
php > var_dump(($test['baz'] ?? null) || ($test['foobar'] ?? null)); // as expected
php shell code:1:
bool(false)
```

Now, what I think happens in test no. 3, is that it get's executed as

```
$test['baz'] ?? (null || $test['foobar']) ?? null
```

so if the `$test['baz']` evaluates to unset (which it obviously does), next `null || $test['foobar']` get's executed, which leads to, `$test['foobar']` throwing the notice.

My question: Is this the expected behaviour of the null coalesce operator in PHP? I kind of expected it to bind stronger than for example the `||` (or) operator.
On the other hand, in the RFC (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary), there's an explicit example:

```
var_dump(0 || 2 ?? 3 ? 4 : 5); // ((0 || 2) ?? 3) ? 4 : 5 => int(4)
```

which could indicate, the example above is correct behaviour.

What do you think? Should this get reported as bug? I know It's not a "proper" question, however since I wasn't able to find a bug report/discussion/thread about it, I thought there should be a resource documenting it.
If you/the mods don't agree, I'll remove the question again.

Comment: If the RFC confirms the behavior, why would it be a bug?

Comment: Isn't this just [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). `||` has higher precedence than `??`.

Comment: @PatrickQ It doesn't exactly confirm the behaviour but IMO have a similar case. That's why I've asked.

Comment: @Barmar you're right. Would you mind adding it as answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I don't think an answer is necessary. This is more of an RTM case.

Comment: @PatrickQ so, should I in this case remove the question?

Comment: @PatrickQ I think it's worth answering. Lots of questions here would disappear if users would just read documentation, but many questioners don't know what documentation to look for.

Comment: @Barmar IMO, lots of questions here _should_ disappear for that reason.  But then again, I don't agree with the whole new philosophy here of content for content's sake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple boolean conditions - operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138269/multiple-boolean-conditions-operator-precedence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior due to [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

`||` has higher precedence than `??`, so your original statement is treated as

```
if ($foo['bar'] ?? (false || $foo['baz']) ?? false)
```